# How can I use JS to append a query string parameter to all outbound urls?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, local-storage, redirect

This problem may seem simple enough, but some of the links on my page are embedded in a video iframe, which is not hosted by me. All outbound links are the same however, even the video one, is there a way to force anyone clicking ANY link all all to go to the same url, modifying it only by appending the initial query sting?

Basically the page is sub.mysite.com and all links on it go to mysite.com - What I need is for anyone landing on sub.mysite.com?x=landing to be taken to mysite.com/landing if they click on any link going out of sub.mysite.com, including the video one. Is this at all possible?

I'm thinking something like:

```
var urlParams;
(window.onpopstate = function () {
    var match,
        pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
        query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

    urlParams = {};
    while (match = search.exec(query))
       urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
})();
```

Then something like:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  var a = anchors[i];
  if(a.href) {
    a.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
      this.href = 'mysite.com/' + x;
    }, false);
  }
}
```

But not sure if this would work for the iframe. Is there some blunt way to force redirect absolutely every outbound link? Maybe with some php to help? or an htaccess dynamic rule?

Comment: The browser is not going to let you mess with what goes on in `<iframe>` tags with different source domains than yours.

Comment: Yes I get that, but isn't there any way to redirect all outbound links from a url? They are still leaving sub.mysite.com, whether the button is in the iframe or not.